# Get File Path (ends with folder)

Tags: excel, vba, file-io

I know how to let the user click on a button to navigate to a specific file to open.

**Code:**

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim vaFiles As Variant

    vaFiles = Application.GetOpenFilename()

    ActiveSheet.Range("B9") = vaFiles
End Sub
```

I want a second button that will let the user navigate to a folder to save the `.pdf` file that my program creates.

The problem: The `GetOpenFilename` requires the user to click on a file.  If there's no file in the folder then there's nothing the user can do.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use the `Application.FileDialog` object

```
Sub SelectFolder()
    Dim diaFolder As FileDialog
    Dim selected As Boolean

    ' Open the file dialog
    Set diaFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    diaFolder.AllowMultiSelect = False
    selected = diaFolder.Show

    If selected Then
        MsgBox diaFolder.SelectedItems(1)
    End If

    Set diaFolder = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Need to make sure Office [version] Object Library is selected (different than Access Library) in References. Otherwise you receive an "automation error".

Answer (score 4):

Have added ErrorHandler to this in case the user hits the cancel button instead of selecting a folder. So instead of getting a horrible error message you get a message that a folder must be selected and then the routine ends. Below code also stores the folder path in a range name (Which is just linked to cell A1 on a sheet).

```
Sub SelectFolder()

Dim diaFolder As FileDialog

'Open the file dialog
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
Set diaFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
diaFolder.AllowMultiSelect = False
diaFolder.Title = "Select a folder then hit OK"
diaFolder.Show
Range("IC_Files_Path").Value = diaFolder.SelectedItems(1)
Set diaFolder = Nothing
Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
Msg = "No folder selected, you must select a folder for program to run"
Style = vbError
Title = "Need to Select Folder"
Response = MsgBox(Msg, Style, Title)

End Sub
```

Comment: The `.Show` method of the FileDialog returns either `TRUE` (if the user has selected a file or files) or `FALSE` (if the user clicked cancel button or closed the window)

Answer (score 3):

In the VBA Editor's Tools menu, click References... scroll down to "Microsoft Shell Controls And Automation" and choose it.

```
Sub FolderSelection()
    Dim MyPath As String
    MyPath = SelectFolder("Select Folder", "")
    If Len(MyPath) Then
        MsgBox MyPath
    Else
        MsgBox "Cancel was pressed"
    End If
End Sub

'Both arguements are optional. The first is the dialog caption and
'the second is is to specify the top-most visible folder in the
'hierarchy. The default is "My Computer."

Function SelectFolder(Optional Title As String, Optional TopFolder _
                         As String) As String
    Dim objShell As New Shell32.Shell
    Dim objFolder As Shell32.Folder

'If you use 16384 instead of 1 on the next line,
'files are also displayed
    Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder _
                            (0, Title, 1, TopFolder)
    If Not objFolder Is Nothing Then
        SelectFolder = objFolder.Items.Item.Path
    End If
End Function
```

[Source Link](http://www.your-save-time-and-improve-quality-technologies-online-resource.com/vba-select-folder.html).

Answer (score 1):

This might help you out:

```
Sub SelectFolder()
    Dim diaFolder As FileDialog
    Dim Fname As String

    Set diaFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    diaFolder.AllowMultiSelect = False
    diaFolder.Show

    Fname = diaFolder.SelectedItems(1)

    ActiveSheet.Range("B9") = Fname

End Sub
```

Comment: Please indent the answer properly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to browse to a folder by default:
For example "D:\Default_Folder"
just initialise the "InitialFileName" attribute

```
Dim diaFolder As FileDialog

' Open the file dialog
Set diaFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
diaFolder.AllowMultiSelect = False
diaFolder.InitialFileName = "D:\Default_Folder"
diaFolder.Show
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Application.GetSaveAsFilename()` in the same way that you used  `Application.GetOpenFilename()`

Comment: If the folder is empty and I click the "Save" button nothing happens.  I was hoping that when you click the "Save" or "Open" button it would exit out of the browser and then, in this case, save the file path to the specified cell.  Thank you for replying

Comment: Hopefully my explanation of what happens is clear.  If I choose an empty folder as the targetted save path and then press "cancel" the text in my specified cell becomes "FALSE".  When I run the program it does work, but it doesn't tell the user what folder the pdf file is being saved to (though they chose it) and when it gets saved the word "FALSE" appears at the beginning such that "FALSEOutput_report.pdf" instead of "Output_report.pdf".  Can someone explain why it works like this?  Thank you

Comment: @Jesse The function returns false if you click cancel and the filename otherwise.  I'm not sure why it's concatenating FALSE to the start of the filename in certain cases.  Part of the confusion could be that this function is just obtaining a file name for you, it isn't doing any saving for you.  That part is up to your program.