# Adding "Browse for folder' option for a merging macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have under mentioned code for merging excel files into one workbook with multiple sheets. It works perfectly. I want some help to add "Browse for folder" function to this code. So, that user can choose which folder contain the source workbooks. Please help.

```
Sub Merge2MultiSheets()
Dim wbDst As Workbook
Dim wbSrc As Workbook
Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
Dim MyPath As String
Dim strFileName As String

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
MyPath = "C:\Jude" ' change to suit
Set wbDst = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
strFileName = Dir(MyPath & "\*.xlsx", vbNormal)



If Len(strFileName) = 0 Then Exit Sub

Do Until strFileName = ""

        Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=MyPath & "\" & strFileName)

        Set wsSrc = wbSrc.Worksheets(1)

        wsSrc.Copy After:=wbDst.Worksheets(wbDst.Worksheets.Count)

        wbDst.Worksheets(wbDst.Worksheets.Count).Name = strFileName

       wbSrc.Close False

    strFileName = Dir()

Loop
wbDst.Worksheets(1).Delete

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I tried the code below. But it gives error. Please look.

```
Function GetFolder(strPath As String, fldSt As String) As String
Dim fldr As FileDialog
Dim sItem As String
Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With fldr
    .Title = fldSt
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = strPath
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
NextCode:
GetFolder = sItem
Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
Sub Getsheets()
Dim wbDst As Workbook
Dim wbSrc As Workbook
Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
Dim MyPath As String
Dim strFileName As String


Path = GetFolder("C:\", "Select an Input Folder") & Application.PathSeparator

Set wbDst = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)

strFileName = Dir(Path & "*.xls?")

Do While Filename <> ""

        Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True)

        Set wsSrc = wbSrc.Worksheets(1)

        wsSrc.Copy After:=wbDst.Worksheets(wbDst.Worksheets.Count)

        wbDst.Worksheets(wbDst.Worksheets.Count).Name = strFileName

       wbSrc.Close False

    strFileName = Dir()

Loop

wbDst.Worksheets(1).Delete

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [VBA Excel Getting File Path (ends with folder)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971292/vba-excel-getting-file-path-ends-with-folder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include:

```
Function GetFolder() As String
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
    GetFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

and then in your **Sub**

```
MyPath = GetFolder
```

as a replacement for:

```
MyPath = "C:\Jude" ' change to suit
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. But it gives an run time error "1004" stating " A workbook must contain at least one visible worksheet". The thing is when I run the macro on the top for the same folder does my task well.

Comment: Post the version of the code with **my function included** and we will debug it.