# Prompt the file name from the cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I am placing a button on an Excel sheet which would save as the current worksheet to a separate file. Following is the code I am using:

```
Sub SaveWorkbook()

ActiveSheet.Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
"C:\Users\username\Downloads\New folder" & ActiveSheet.Name & ".xlsx", FileFormat:= _
xlExcel8, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False _
, CreateBackup:=False

End Sub
```

Here instead of sheet name (ActiveSheet.Name), I want to place the text from the cell (D2:E2, both the cells are merged).

Is it possible to do?

Also here I have explicitly mentioned the path.

Is it possible to make it prompt to choose the path to save it?

While choosing the path, the name can be taken from the cell?

Update:

```
Sub SelectFolder()
    Dim diaFolder As FileDialog

    Set diaFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    diaFolder.AllowMultiSelect = False
    diaFolder.Show
    ActiveSheet.Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    diaFolder & ActiveSheet.[d2] & ".xlsx", FileFormat:= _
    xlExcel8, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False _
, CreateBackup:=False

    Set diaFolder = Nothing
End Sub
```

Can you see what is the mistake here? the file is not saving in the selected path.

Comment: Yes, just use .Range("D2:E2").Value  You may only need D2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `ActiveSheet.Name` with `ActiveSheet.[d2]` .

That will pull the value from the merged cell.

As far as getting the path from the user, it easy with:

```
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5975453/3566998

Comment: @ Excel Hero Thanks a lot... I am able to replace the value from d2. But not able to put the second one. Can you edit the code given in the question?

Comment: I've given you the correct target to shoot for. Why would you un-accept my answer?

Comment: I tried the code fitting into my code. But I am getting some errors. Can you see what is the problem? The it is prompting for selecting the folder, file gets saved, but not in the selected path.

Comment: Please ask a new question.

Comment: It would be related. Normally, it's best to ask one question in a posted question here. You asked two questions and received an answer for both. You then updated your post with those answers. It's better to ask a new question for what specifically does not work now.