# Excel 2016 - Compile Error in Hidden Module

Tags: vba, excel

I'm creating a simple report excel where it merge xls files when user select a folder. It was working perfectly until when i test in different PC, i got " Compile Error in Hidden Module" error. Below is the screenshot of the error.

[image]

Below are the MergeSheets module codes that i got from internet.

```
Option Explicit
Public strPath As String
Public Type SELECTINFO
hOwner As Long
pidlRoot As Long
pszDisplayName As String
lpszTitle As String
ulFlags As Long
lpfn As Long
lParam As Long
iImage As Long
End Type

Declare Function SHGetPathFromIDList Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "SHGetPathFromIDListA" (ByVal pidl As Long, ByVal pszPath As String) As Long
Declare Function SHBrowseForFolder Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "SHBrowseForFolderA" (lpBrowseInfo As SELECTINFO) As Long
Function SelectFolder(Optional Msg) As String
Dim sInfo As SELECTINFO
Dim path As String
Dim r As Long, x As Long, pos As Integer
sInfo.pidlRoot = 0&

If IsMissing(Msg) Then
    sInfo.lpszTitle = "Select your folder."
Else
    sInfo.lpszTitle = Msg
End If

sInfo.ulFlags = &H1

x = SHBrowseForFolder(sInfo)

path = Space$(512)
r = SHGetPathFromIDList(ByVal x, ByVal path)
If r Then
    pos = InStr(path, Chr$(0))
    SelectFolder = Left(path, pos - 1)
Else
    SelectFolder = ""
End If
End Function

"Merging Part"
Sub MergeExcels()
Dim path As String, ThisWB As String, lngFilecounter As Long
Dim wbDest As Workbook, shtDest As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
Dim Filename As String, Wkb As Workbook
Dim CopyRng As Range, Dest As Range
Dim RowofCopySheet As Integer

RowofCopySheet = 1 

ThisWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name

path = SelectFolder("Select a folder containing Excel files you want to merge")

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set shtDest = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Filename = Dir(path & "\*.xls", vbNormal)
If Len(Filename) = 0 Then Exit Sub
Do Until Filename = vbNullString
    If Not Filename = ThisWB Then
        Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=path & "\" & Filename)
        Set CopyRng = Wkb.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(RowofCopySheet, 1), Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count))
        Set Dest = shtDest.Range("A" & shtDest.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1)
        CopyRng.Copy Dest
        Wkb.Close False
    End If

    Filename = Dir()
Loop

Range("A1").Select

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Files Merged!"
End Sub
```

I managed find the source of problem which is the incompatibility of 32bit and 64bit OS. And i managed to find the solution where i need to include PtrSafe into my declare part. After i include the "PtrSafe" as below, the error is not showing up anymore.

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SHGetPathFromIDList Lib "shell32.dll" _
                                 Alias "SHGetPathFromIDListA" (ByVal pidl As Long, ByVal pszPath As String) As Long


Private Declare PtrSafe Function SHBrowseForFolder Lib "shell32.dll" _
                               Alias "SHBrowseForFolderA" (lpBrowseInfo As SELECTINFO) As Long
```

However when i execute the code, my Excel program crash.

Although this code is created for 32bit OS, it is working when i developing on my PC which is 64bit version. I even tried the same code on 2nd PC which also 64bit. However when i tried on 3rd PC which also 64bit, the error showed up.

Hope you give can give idea for this. Thanks.

Comment: The problem is probably with the versions of office rather than with the version of the OS. Check if you are using 32bits or 64bits versions of Office.

Comment: You can't just add `PtrSafe` to your declarations and expect them to work.  You also need to replace any pointer parameters with `LongPtr`.  That said, what's wrong with using [the Application.FileDialog object](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5975453/4088852)?

Comment: @VincentG, you are correct. The code working in Excel 32bits and not working in 3rd pc which is running 64bit Office. Any solution apart from above?

Comment: @Comintern, thanks for the advice. i changed all the Long to LongPtr and tried to run but i get new error which is "Run-time error '1004' Cannot run macro".

Comment: @Comintern, reason why is not using Application.FileDialog object is I dont know how to choose the folder and merge all by using Application.FileDialog object. I can choose single file by using that but not multiple files. new to excel vba

Comment: The [linked answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5975453/4088852) does ***exactly the same thing as your API call***.  Delete everything above `"Merging Part"`, copy the code in the lined answer, change `Sub SelectFolder()` to `Function SelectFolder(Optional msg As String) As String`, add the line `diaFolder.Title = msg` above `diaFolder.Show` and replace `MsgBox` with `SelectFolder =`.

Comment: @Comintern, you are God dude. thank you. worked exactly as i want.