# Get Folder Path as String

Tags: excel, vba

I'm relatively new with VBA and currently working on a macro that will change from PC to PC, for test purposes I'm using the direct path:

```
Sub VIP()

'Define Folder Paths & Workbooks

Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\j.lopez\Documents\AdHoc Reports\Serrano\Daily VIP Report Master.xlsx")
```

to open the workbooks, but eventually that path will change, so i was thinking to make the user select the folder path with:

```
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
```

But im lost, how can i properly:

- 1.- Ask for a user to select the folder containing the necessary files for the macro to work with
- 2.- Trap that path
- 3.- Replace it in the WorkBooks.Open

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA Excel Getting File Path (ends with folder)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971292/vba-excel-getting-file-path-ends-with-folder)

Comment: Have you googled that? You’ll find literally 100’s of examples.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. Actually this is what i needed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y4PG2qr9tRM

Answer (score 1):

Selecting file or folder with Browse File Option with VBA

```
' To Select File 

sub select_file()
selected_file = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "Select File", , False)
End sub

' To Select Folder

Sub selectfolder()

zhr_folder = GetFolder()

End sub



Function GetFolder() As String

Dim fldr As FileDialog

Dim sItem As String

Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With fldr

    .Title = "Select a Folder"

    .AllowMultiSelect = False

    .InitialFileName = ""

    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode

    sItem = .SelectedItems(1)

End With

NextCode:

GetFolder = sItem

Set fldr = Nothing

End Function
```

Post that you can combine both file and folder names to adapt your needs

Source: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vbausefulcodes.dp

Answer (score 0):

**1. Ask for a user to select the folder containing the necessary files for the macro to work with:**

I would recommend you to use **FolderDialog** and **Show** the **Dialog** to the user, and let him/her choose the folder. Next, check whether the required files exist in the selected directory. Use `System.IO.File.Exists(<path>)=<boolean>` .

**2. Trap that path:**

Just after validating the folder path, you can save the folder path in a variable.
Then do an assignment statement,
Let's say you created a variable '**path**', so, `path = path & "\" & <file_name>` .
And there you have it, stored in '**path**'.

**3. Replace it in the WorkBooks.Open:**

Then use the following code:

```
Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\j.lopez\Documents\AdHoc Reports\Serrano\" & path)
```

Answer (score -1):

EDIT-

This code was adapted to my needs, and i found it on this YouTube Video

```
Dim diaFolder As FileDialog

Set diaFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
diaFolder.AllowMultiSelect = False
diaFolder.Show

fle = diaFolder.SelectedItems(1)

Range("A15") = fle

Set diaFolder = Nothing

'Opening WorkBooks

Workbooks.Open (fle & "\Daily Sports VIP Report.xlsx")
```

video for Reference 
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y4PG2qr9tRM

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22458227)

Comment: Got it! Thank you for the review