Check for valid user input file path
I'm working on a macro for work and at the end, trying to save. It's going to be accessible to a group so the place to save the file will not be static.
I ask the user to specify where the file should be saved, and kick out an error if the file path is not valid.
It says I have an invalid file path.
Dim CurrDate As String
Dim SaveLoc As String
Dim SaveBook As String

CurrDate = Format(Date, "MMDDYY")

SaveLoc = InputBox("Please specify the folder with file path where you would like to save your file:")
SaveBook = SaveLoc + "\" + "MyFile - " & CurrDate

If Dir(SaveBook) <> "" Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=SaveBook
Else
    MsgBox "File path does not exist. Please enter a valid file path:"
End If


Have you tried it with a file extension included in SaveBook? Also, you will want to check the results of SaveLoc before continuing in case the user cancels, or enters anything that causes it to not be valid. You may find this useful right before the SaveAs line: Debug.Print SaveBook - then look at your immediate window when you get an error.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5975453. Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker) instead of InputBox

Side note: SaveLoc + "\" + "MyFile - " & CurrDate should use & instead of +.

If Dir(SaveBook) <> "" Then is asking if there's already a file with that name in the location the user selected.  If you want to check whether the user-supplied path is valid you'd test using Dir(SaveLoc, vbDirectory)

There is a better alternative to InputBox.
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

Link to microsoft Learn of Excel.Application.FileDialog
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = "xxx"
    If .Show = -1 Then ' if OK is pressed
        sFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
        'create file in folder
    End If
End With


Save an Excel File to Another Location

Entering a path is a drag. Rather use the File Dialog object to let the user select the folder. The PickFolder helper function opens the dialog and returns the path of the selected folder, or an empty string if the dialog is canceled.
Although you need not specify the file extension when saving as a .xlsx file, do it anyway.
If a workbook was never saved, you cannot use Save to save it.
The following also covers a few other surprises lurking.

Main
Sub SaveExcelFile()
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Save Excel File"
    On Error GoTo ClearError

    Const DIALOG_TITLE As String = "Pick the Save Location"
    Const FILE_NAME_PREFIX As String = "MyFile - "
    Const FILE_EXTENSION As String = ".xlsx"
    Const FILE_FORMAT As Long = xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    Const DATE_FORMAT As String = "MMDDYY"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    ' If the workbook is supposed to be the workbook containing this code,
    ' use 'ThisWorkbook' instead of 'ActiveWorkbook'.
    
    Dim FolderPath As String: FolderPath = PickFolder(, DIALOG_TITLE)
    
    If Len(FolderPath) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Folder dialog canceled!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        GoTo ProcExit
    End If
        
    Dim FilePath As String: FilePath = FolderPath & FILE_NAME_PREFIX _
        & Format(Date, DATE_FORMAT) & FILE_EXTENSION
    
    Dim OverwriteAnswer As Long
    
    If Len(Dir(FilePath)) > 0 Then ' file exists
        OverwriteAnswer = MsgBox("The file """ & FilePath _
            & """ already exists!" & vbLf & vbLf _
            & "Do you want to overwrite it?", _
            vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, PROC_TITLE)
        If OverwriteAnswer = vbNo Then
            MsgBox "File save canceled!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
            GoTo ProcExit
        End If
    End If
        
    If Len(wb.Path) = 0 Then ' workbook was never saved
        ' cannot use 'Save'; can still use 'SaveAs'
    Else ' workbook was previously saved
        If Not wb.Saved Then wb.Save ' save only if not saved (efficiency)
    End If
    
    Dim ErrNumber As Long
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' prevent file exists & file format alerts
        On Error Resume Next ' prevent error if invalid file path
            wb.SaveAs Filename:=FilePath, FileFormat:=FILE_FORMAT
            ErrNumber = Err.Number
        On Error GoTo ClearError
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    If ErrNumber <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Could not save the file as """ & FilePath & """!", _
            vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    MsgBox "File saved as """ & FilePath & """.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
    
ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description, vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub

Help
Function PickFolder( _
    Optional InitialFolderPath As String = "", _
    Optional DialogTitle As String = "Browse", _
    Optional DialogButtonName As String = "OK", _
    Optional ShowCancelMessage As Boolean = False) _
As String
    With Application.FileDialog(4) ' 4 = msoFileDialogFolderPicker
        .Title = DialogTitle
        .ButtonName = DialogButtonName
        Dim pSep As String: pSep = Application.PathSeparator
        Dim FolderPath As String
        ' Note that the following 'If' statement is NOT redundant.
        If Len(InitialFolderPath) > 0 Then
            If Right(InitialFolderPath, 1) = pSep Then
                FolderPath = InitialFolderPath
            Else
                FolderPath = InitialFolderPath & pSep
            End If
            .InitialFileName = FolderPath
        End If
        If .Show Then
            FolderPath = .SelectedItems(1)
            If Right(FolderPath, 1) <> pSep Then FolderPath = FolderPath & pSep
            PickFolder = FolderPath
        Else
            If ShowCancelMessage Then
                MsgBox "Folder dialog canceled!", vbExclamation, "Pick Folder"
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Function

